# Introduction to complex tensor algebra

Tags: book-recommendation, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I am looking for some reading material that would encompass tensor algebra on complex hermitian spaces (not necessarily complex manifolds).
Of course I looked in every tensor algebra course I could put my hands on, but complex spaces are never discussed.

What I could find was complex differential geometry, kahler manifolds and such, but it's way too far off...
I'm only interested in the basic definitions of tensors (covariant/contravariant components, metric tensor, etc.) over complex spaces and especially how complex conjugation is treated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading *Modern Geometry — Methods and Applications
Part I. The Geometry of Surfaces, Transformation Groups, and Fields* by
B. A. DubrovinA. T. FomenkoS. P. Novikov

https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4684-9946-9

The section 11 and section 27 treat the case complexe, though I have also some doubts in this materiel. We can discuss if you like.

Comment: I browsed it and I don't remember it touching the subject, but I'll take another look, thanks.